# miで編集したスクリプトを実行しても何も起きず、lessで表示すると改行がおかしくなっている

Tags: macos, perl, 文字化け, テキストファイル

Mac OS XでPerlの（というか初めてのプログラミングの）勉強を始めました。

スクリプトファイルを作るのには、miというテキストエディタを使っていますが、なぜか実行できるものとできないものがあります。実行できないものは、ターミナルで文法チェックにかけています。

```
% perl -cw broken.pl
% broken.pl syntax OK
```

「ハローワールド」と表示するだけの単純なスクリプトなのですが、なにも起こらず次の行ができます。

```
% perl broken.pl
% [] <-これはカーソル
```

覚えていないだけで実行できるファイルと違った作り方をしているのだと思いますが、Perlのスクリプトファイルを作るときに気をつけるべき点を教えてください。

最終的には、別のテキストファイルを変更することを目指して勉強しているのですが、操作対象のファイルでも形式上の制約があるのでしょうか？

編集
コメントにお応えしてcatの結果を引用します。

```
bash-3.2$ cat broken.pl
print "$embedded 表示されたら合格。\n";
```

エディタで入力したスクリプト（以下の画像）の一部に過ぎません。
[image: 入力したスクリプト]

そこで確実に全部の内容を見るためにcatにつづけて | lessを使いました。一部文字化けではないかとおもわれるところがあるので画像で示します。
[image: 入力したスクリプトの全景]

Perlのバージョンは

```
bash-3.2$ perl -v |grep This
This is perl, v5.10.0 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

です。初めに調べるべきでした。多分古すぎるのでしょうか。

Comment: 不思議ですね。質問を編集して、`cat broken.pl`の出力を省略なく貼り付けてみて下さい。

Comment: broken.plの中身を追記してもらえますか？スクリプトの中身が分かれば回答を得やすくなると思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

（mztnsさんの回答と同じですが補足として一応）

スクリプトに含まれている文字`^M`からおそらく、Perlから見ると改行を正しく判断できずに一行だけのファイルだと解釈してしまい、さらに先頭に `#!/usr/bin/perl` があることでスクリプト本体がコメント行扱いされて、結果的に何も出力されなかったようです。

miエディタの改行コードが`CR(Mac)`になっていることが原因かと思います。

エディタのモード設定→デフォルトから「改行コード」を`LF(UNIX)`に設定したのち、
改めてスクリプトを編集・実行してみてください。

Comment: miエディタはいくつものモードをもっていて、モードごとに改行コードが設定できるのですね。標準とPerlモードの両方で改行コードを`LF(UNIX)`にしました。新たに作ったスクリプトは全部動作します。今までに作って動かなかったスクリプトは正規表現などいろいろ試したのですが動くようになりませんでした。不具合の原因の詳しい分析もありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4):

miで改行コードを「LF(UNIX)」にしてみてください